# How can I add the localStorage id to a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-binding, blazor, local-storage

In my code, the List ids did not take the `data.Id` value, taken from `@bind=@data.Id`. The reason for that is unknown. Please, is there any suggestions, because I am new to data binding? The list was printed out by the last Console... line and one got only the ids I added in the begining:

```cs
ids.Add(123456);
ids.Add(1234);
ids.Add(123);
```

Everything worked fine regarding the logic. However, I am trying to check if the current input id is in the ids list.

```html
<input type="int" class="form-control" @bind=@data.Id @bind:event="oninput" placeholder="Enter ID" name="psw" id="psw" required>
```

```cs
   @code{
     private DataModel data = new DataModel();
    
     private List<string> ids = new List<string>();
    
    private async void HandleLogin()
    {
    
        var currentId = await LocalStorage.GetItemAsync<int>("id");
    
        ids.Add(123456);
        ids.Add(1234);
        ids.Add(123);
    
        if(currentId!=0)
        {
            // var usersid = data.Id;
            // var user = users.Where(x => x.Id == data.Id).First();
    
            // if (usersid == user.Id)
            // {
            Console.WriteLine("Already logged in!");
    
            await Task.Delay(1500);
            // confirmation = true;
    
            NavManager.NavigateTo("/enviar");
    
            // }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (!ids.Contains(data.Id))
            {
                var randomId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var usersid = data.Id;
                ids.Add(usersid);
    
                users.Add(new DataModel
                {
                    Id = data.Id,
                    UserId = randomId,
                    SMSCode = null,
                    Token = null
                });
    
                Console.WriteLine("New User Welcome!");
                // Random rnd = new Random();
                // int num = rnd.Next();
    
                // var num = psw.Value;
    
                await LocalStorage.SetItemAsync<int>("id", data.Id);
                await LocalStorage.SetItemAsync<string>("userId", randomId);
                await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    
                NavManager.NavigateTo("/verificar");
            }
            else if(ids.Contains(data.Id))
            {
                var usersid = data.Id;
                var user = users.Where(x => x.Id == usersid).First();
    
                await LocalStorage.SetItemAsync<int>("id", usersid);
                await LocalStorage.SetItemAsync<string>("userId", user.UserId);
                await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    
                Console.WriteLine("Logged In!");
    
                NavManager.NavigateTo("/enviar");
            }
        }
        Console.Write(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, ids));
    }
    }
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: You could try store list of arrays as jsonstring. And parsing them instead.